# Adding a label programmatically in C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to create a paddle using a label which must be done programmatically to a brick breaker game and my aim is so that no matter what desktop computer with different screen sizes I'm using, the paddle will always be in the bottom center of the screen but for some reason the paddle(label) is not showing. This is the code I'm using:

```
Screen userScreen = Screen.PrimaryScreen;
int screenWidth = userScreen.WorkingArea.Width;
int screenHeight = userScreen.WorkingArea.Height;

this.Width = screenWidth;
this.Height = screenHeight;

Label lblPaddle = new Label();
lblPaddle.BackColor = Color.White;          
lblPaddle.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
//lblPaddle.Left = (this.ClientSize.Width - lblPaddle.Width) / 2;
//lblPaddle.Top = (this.ClientSize.Height - lblPaddle.Height) / 2;
//lblPaddle.Size = this.ClientSize;
int lblPaddleWidth = (int)(screenWidth * 0.15);
int lblPaddleHeight = lblPaddle.Height;
int lblPaddleXCoord = (screenWidth / 2) - (lblPaddleWidth / 2);
int lblPaddleYCoord = screenHeight - lblPaddleHeight - (int)(screenHeight * 0.1);
lblPaddle.SetBounds(lblPaddleXCoord, lblPaddleYCoord, lblPaddleWidth, lblPaddleHeight);

this.Controls.Add(lblPaddle);
```

The part where there are comments were different approaches I attempted in order to try and make it work.
Why is it not showing?

Comment: Your `Label` has not `Text` property. Set the `Label`'s `Text` and try again.

Comment: @S.Akbari Its not text that I want. Its just the label with its background colour set to white which acts like a paddle. For the sake of testing I tried adding text property but still nothing appears.

Comment: I think you may want a panel instead of a label... and a control that actually show the position of your "paddle"

Comment: `lblPaddle.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;`

Comment: By default labels are autosized. Which means that if you do not enter any text, it will only be something like 1 pixel wide.

Comment: @VisualVincent It only defaults to AutoSize = true when you use the designer, not when you use code.

Comment: @LarsTech I tried the dockStyle but to no avail :/ but um I would highly prefer if I kept my label instead of a panel

Comment: @LarsTech : Oh? Well then I learnt something new today. :)

Comment: Is the form white?  Do you have any panels or other controls loaded on the form that would hide the label?  I only suggested the Dock-Fill as a way for you to see your control since you are not seeing it, and your sample code was using ClientSize.  A panel is the more appropriate control to use, so I'm not sure why you are stuck on wanting to use a label.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/b7jl2n This is the game screen. The 2 labels here were done programatically with no problems. I do not know why the paddle is acting differently. It is part of an assignment I have and it stricly abides us by using a label for a paddle and I do no intend to deviate from that xD

Comment: There's not even any code here that attempts to position the `Label`, never mind did you provide a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem. Please improve this post if you want an answer. (Not that there aren't already hundreds of similar questions on Stack Overflow, which you should reference first before asking another one...but regardless, it's impossible to help if the question is not good.)

Comment: @PeterDuniho I took your advice and tried to improve the question and show more code. Is it better now? I'm still a beginner. My apologies for that, but honestly I really don't know why the label is not showing on my screen

Comment: @CyanicWolf FWIW, I have absolutely no problem with your code. I created a blank WinForms project, pasted your code into an Init method that I called immediately after the `InitializeComponent` call, and there it is. A white label at the bottom with a solid border.

Comment: Please read the information at the link I provided previously, to understand what kind of code example is required. Whatever the problem you're having, no doubt it's a fairly simple one to address, but without a way to reproduce your problem, it's not possible to say how to fix it. See also [ask] for additional information on how to present your question in a clear, answerable way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have absolutely no problems with your code when called like this:

```
   public partial class Form1 : Form
   {
      public Form1()
      {
         InitializeComponent();
         InitLabel();
      }

      private void InitLabel()
      {
         Screen userScreen = Screen.PrimaryScreen;
         int screenWidth = userScreen.WorkingArea.Width;
         int screenHeight = userScreen.WorkingArea.Height;

         this.Width = screenWidth;
         this.Height = screenHeight;

         // I added the following 2 lines because the form was below the task bar
         this.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
         this.Location = new Point(0,0);

         Label lblPaddle = new Label();
         lblPaddle.Name = "lblPaddle";
         lblPaddle.BackColor = Color.White;
         lblPaddle.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
         int lblPaddleWidth = (int)(screenWidth * 0.15);
         int lblPaddleHeight = lblPaddle.Height;
         int lblPaddleXCoord = (screenWidth / 2) - (lblPaddleWidth / 2);
         int lblPaddleYCoord = screenHeight - lblPaddleHeight - (int)(screenHeight * 0.1);
         lblPaddle.SetBounds(lblPaddleXCoord, lblPaddleYCoord, lblPaddleWidth, lblPaddleHeight);

         this.Controls.Add(lblPaddle);
      }
   }
```

It ends up looking like this:

[image: Scaled down screenshot]

**EDIT:** If you're planning to do anything with it, I suggest giving it a name. I added it above.

Answer (score 0):

For some odd reason this was not working. I spoke with a lecturer at my school and she also could not figure out what the problem was. Perhaps it was a bug of some sort. The only way I managed to resolve this was by creating another form and create another paddle and then I copied the code from the form I created to the original and it worked. Neither me nor the lecturer could figure out what the problem was. It was just plain weird since the code was basically the same.